# Login functionality not running

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have created the functionality and API to check the given password against a stored hash, but for some reason the remainder of my function is never running.

Below is my login function:

```
 login() {
        //below calls the checkHash() API to see if the values passed into html are true user values
        //showLoading();
        console.log("login stuff");
        console.log(this.username);
        console.log(this.password);
        this.checkLogin(this.username, this.password)
        .then(data => {
                console.log("login credentials");
                console.log(data);
                if(data == "yes"){
                        //this means the login credentials were correct
                        this.navCtrl.push(AllPatientsPage);
                        console.log("data is equal");
                }
                else{
                        //this means the login credentials were incorrect
                        this.showPopup("Login Error", "Incorrect Credentials");
                        console.log("data not correct");
                }
        });
 }
```

below is the checkLogin func:

```
checkLogin(username, password) {
   return this.restService.checkHash(this.username, this.password);
}
```

I have tested the API I am using through postman and it is returning the "yes" response as expected.  The app never pushes to next page or prints out to console.

Rest Services code:

```
checkHash(username, password) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
                        //var inData = ("/" + username + "/" + password);
            console.log("below is username");
            console.log(username);
            console.log("below is password");
            console.log(password);

            this.http.post('http://url/checkHash/'+username, '/' + password)
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log("checkHash");
                console.log(res);
                resolve(res);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you update question to include the restService method?

Comment: Which url is working with postman? Or could you give the right url & params to post ?

Comment: @Fetrarij The same URL post being called in RestServices post call.  and I have tested it in both the web browser and postman, the .then call is just never seeming to run